# How to clear TextBox text and AJAX CalendarExtender value using Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET user control that contains a textbox which has an AJAX CalendarExtender control which allows users to select a date which then populates the textbox.

I can clear the textbox value using a submit button and setting the value to null in the code behind, but I need to set the value to "" in the textbox using Javascript.

I have tried the following javascript but it didn't work:

```
function ClearTextBox() 
{
    document.getElementsByName('TextBox1').Value = "";
}
```

What javascript should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of `Value` => `value`.   JavaScript is case sensitive...
- `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements so select the first element with `[0]`

---

```
document.getElementsByName('TextBox1')[0].value = "";
```

or select the element by id:

```
document.getElementById('TextBoxId').value = "";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't clear the textbox. Would it being in a user control cause this? Also, there is an AJAX CalendarExtender being used with the textbox - would this need to be set to null or empty string?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser. Try get the element by it's `id`, `id` _should_ be unique.

Comment: It clears other textboxes, but not the textbox with the calendar extender.

Comment: @aspdotnetuser. I never used that control. Check with Firebug where the value is saved, and clear it.